# How to set the heap size of a JEE application?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web, heap-size

I am developing a web classified web site using jsp, java and servlets.

My requirements are:

- images
- 2gb web size
- database
- category list with fully functional classified web site.

So far, my web host provider gives me 128mb heap size.

How can I calculate my web site heap size need? Tell me if 128mb heap size will fulfill my initial recurements.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. What research have you done on this subject? Have you looked through your hosting providers docs on this? Have you looked through the java docs on this? Why was your research  not helpful? What have you tried to do to figure it out yourself?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title would appear to be 'contact the hosting provider' (in this case; or '[pass the relevant JVM argument(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)' more generally).  As for the rest, there aren't really enough details here to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Heap size depends upon the actual live objects present at a time when your application is running. You can use a profiler like `jprofiler`, `visualvm` to profile your application simulating the maximum load you want to put at a time.
You can use the tips provid in below useful links to find the heap requirement of your application
http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2012/07/5-tips-for-proper-java-heap-size.html
http://docs.oracle.com/html/A90444_01/sizing.htm
Also you can always do heap settings for JVM,provided you have enough RAM.

Comment: While not incorrect, the JVM will impose a fixed maximum size that the heap can grow to.  If memory demands exceed the maximum size, you'll start getting `OutOfMemoryError`s.  I think the OP probably wants to know how to increase the JVM's maximum limit.